# Equivalent GCC -mpush-args flag for Clang

Tags: gcc, stack, clang, cpu-registers

I'm trying to call a C function from some x86 assembly. The C code was compiled with Clang:

```
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

I'm depending on pushing function arguments onto the stack for calling, but clang doesn't seem to directly allow for functions to accept parameters from the stack. Instead, it uses a mix of stack offsets and register moves to manipulate the parameters. For GCC, there is the flag `-mpush-args` that allows you to provide arguments through the stack, and nothing else. Since I'm using Clang this flag isn't available. I have done around an hour of research to find an equivalent flag for Clang, but I haven't been able to find one. Does anyone know if there is an equivalent flag for Clang?

Here are my arguments to the code:
`-mstackrealign -fverbose-asm -S -masm=intel -O0`

Comment: While you say "x86 assembly," I'm guessing you really mean x86_64.  Designers tried hard to standardize the calling conventions when the world moved to 64bit (and still Windows and Linux went two different ways).  Trying to force your C code to violate that convention may be possible, but are you sure you want to?  Seems like you'd just be setting yourself up for future grief.  If re-working your asm is out of the question, how about passing a `void *` to the stack?  Only takes 1 register, and the stack is unchanged.  Call a c wrapper, and you can call the original func with a bit of work.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd I'll try that out.